# order by What are 1, 2 in alignment?

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

```
select empno , deptno , sal from emp
order by 1,2
```

What are 1, 2 in alignment?

What is one and two? Why don't you write the column name?

Comment: They are positions (refering to the columns in the select clause). 1 = empno, 2 = deptno. They are quick to write, but many people, including myself, never use them. I prefer to write the column names explicitely.

Comment: Orders by column 1, then column 2, i.e., empno , deptno.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2171079): ***position**:
Specify position to order rows based on their value for the expression in this position of the select list. The position value must be an **integer**.* Note, that it is a integer literal, not some expression that evaluates to integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query language defines this as a shortcut.

```
select empno , deptno , sal from emp
order by 1,2
```

```
select empno , deptno , sal from emp
order by empno, deptno
```

mean precisely the same thing. The numbers refer to the column numbers in your SELECT, counting from 1.

The shortcut comes in handy if you have stuff like

```
select CONCAT(surname, ', ', givenname) name, empno , deptno , sal from emp
order by 1
```

because it saves typing. In standard SQL you'd have to write that query

```
select CONCAT(surname, ', ', givenname) name, empno , deptno , sal from emp
order by CONCAT(surname, ', ', givenname)
```

Use whichever one you please. But be careful; it makes your ORDER BY clause dependent on the order of items in your SELECT clause. The next person to work on your code may not be expecting such a dependency. Especially if that next person is you.

Comment: Yep, three characters saved. `1` instead of `name` :-)

Comment: In standard SQL you can order by the alias name (`ORDER BY name`), but yes, you can also order by the expression itself.

Answer (score 2):

It works just the same, whether you use

```
order by empno, deptno
```

or

```
order by 1, 2
```

---

Note that - although *positional* sorting requires less typing, you have to synchronize such an `order by` clause with every `select` column list rearrangement. I never use it (except for *quick & dirty* testing queries).